# Rotate image *without* resizing it

Tags: php

I would like to rotate an image (with a user-defined angle of rotation), but without making the image smaller.

[image]

1. is what happens already, saving the shaded area as a smaller image
2. is what I would like, the dashed line being the new image size.

The server has PHP 5.3+. Links, code and explanations all very welcome.

Comment: It would help to know how you're rotating the image.

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php and checkout the `imagerotateEquivalent()` function. I think something like that could be used to achive something like this.

Comment: Seems you "did a lot of Googling" but didn't think to look through the comments on `imagerotate`'s manual page.

Answer (score 2):

This is not complete answer but I would take the four corners as coordinates rotate them by your angle and then calculate the new bounding box based on the extent of the new coordinates.
(assuming coordinates with origin on the bottom left).

```
corners = rotate_each ( [(left,top) (left,bottom), (right,top), (right,bottom)], angle)
new_bb_left = min([corners[0].x, corners[1].x, corners[2].x, corners[3].x])
new_bb_right = max([corners[0].x, corners[1].x, corners[2].x, corners[3].x])
new_bb_bottom = min([corners[0].y, corners[1].y, corners[2].y, corners[3].y])
new_bb_top = max([corners[0].y, corners[1].y, corners[2].y, corners[3].y])
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way to do it. Calculate the diagonal width.

[image: Check this image for the formula]

PHP has a Square root function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php
In that way you should have the diagonal width which you could apply on the transformed image.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions including the trigonometric formulas but this library seems to be the shortcut.

http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Example: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=rotate&output=preset%20for%20demo&colors=255&dither=1&match_palette=1